# Passing a parameter in p5.Element method

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, parameters, p5.js

I was experimenting with p5 and the DOM. I created a simple example with some sliders and buttons to print text in the browser.

Why can't I pass a parameter when using the method mousePressed()?
What I mean is it giving me an error when I try to do `sButton.mousePressed('Swordsman');`

Here below is my code. Sorry if it is a mess I just started experimenting with this.

```js
let sSlider, aSlider, cSlider;
let sInput, aInput, cInput;
let sButton, aButton, cButton;
let parS, parA, parC;
let totalS, totalA, totalC;
totalS = totalA = totalC = 0;

function setup() {
  createElement('h1', 'Recruit Troops');

  createElement('b', 'Swordsman: ');
  sInput = createInput('');
  sSlider = createSlider(0, 999, 0);
  sButton = createButton('recruit');
  parS = createP('');
  parS.hide();

  sButton.mousePressed(recruting('Swordsman'));
  createElement('br');

  createElement('b', 'Archer');
  aInput = createInput('');
  aSlider = createSlider(0, 999, 0);
  aButton = createButton('recruit');
  parA = createP('');
  parA.hide();

  aButton.mousePressed(recruting('Archer'));
  createElement('br');

  createElement('b', 'Cavalry');
  cInput = createInput('');
  cSlider = createSlider(0, 999, 0);
  cButton = createButton('recruit');
  parC = createP('');
  parC.hide();

  cButton.mousePressed(recruting('Cavalry'));
  createElement('br');
}



function draw() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  background(255);
  updateValues();
}


function updateValues() {
  sInput.value(sSlider.value());
  aInput.value(aSlider.value());
  cInput.value(cSlider.value());
}

function recruting(troop) {
  if (troop == 'Swordsman') {
    totalS += sSlider.value()
    parS.html(+totalS + '' + troop + ' recruting');
  } else if (troop == 'Archer') {
    totalA += aSlider.value();
    parA.html(+totalA + '' + troop + ' recruting');
  } else if (troop == 'Cavalry') {
    totalC += cSlider.value();
    parC.html(+totalC + '' + troop + ' recruting');
  }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you get? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: But he did? Or did he add it? Then good on him for playing by the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible. You have to add an extra function. Let me explain.

The method mousePressed() takes a function as an argument. You could call it a 'callback function'. When you press the dom element, it calls the function that you pass into there.

```
let c = createButton('test');
c.mousePressed( doSomething );

function doSomething( msg ){
    console.log(msg); //expected output: undefined

}
```

Note how I passed 'doSomething' without the (). The () mean you are executing (calling) that function. You only want to pass in a reference to the whole function.

** If I did add the (), the function would directly be executed and whatever the function returns (undefined in this case) would be passed in as the callback function.

When you add an extra function to the mousePressed arguments, you can call doSomething from within that function.

```
let c = createButton('test');
c.mousePressed( function(){
    doSomething('Hello Vasco!');
});

function doSomething( msg ){
    console.log(msg); //expected output: Hello Vasco!

}
```

Or, applying it to your code it should look like this:

```
cButton.mousePressed( function(){
    recruting('Cavalry');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very clarifying answer! It worked perfectly, And I learned that I can create a function inside de arguments, that is something that I didn't know!